# ValueError: Negative values in data passed to LatentDirichletAllocation.fit

Tags: python, lda

I'm trying to get the features sub-space that maximizes the separation between classes, using LDA, but the script raises the error  `ValueError: Negative values in data passed to LatentDirichletAllocation.fit`

I't cannot be used with negative data? Or what's the problem?
I've been searching but no answers found...

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are using **Latent Dirichlet Allocation**:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation as LDA
```

What you want to use is **Linear Discriminant Analysis**:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
```

Both are abbreviated "LDA" and hence the confusion.